# Which one is better amongst right shifting the number and left shifting the bit mask when checking for whether is bit set at the specified position?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to figure out a problem which asks for checking whether the kth bit is set or not and I have implemented in the following manner using: 
Left shift the mask

```
public static boolean leftShiftingMask(int num, int pos){
    return (num & (1 << pos)) != 0;
  }
```

Right shift the number

```
public static boolean rightShiftingNumber(int num, int pos){
    return ((num >> pos) & 1) != 0;
  }
```

Now, in this case both methods have O(1) complexity, but I just want to know that whether left shifting the mask to the desired position is better than right shifting the original number to the desired position or vice-versa is better or both are equivalent?

And one more thing that while checking for whether the bit is set or not, should the position entered by the user should start from 0 or 1, since the place value begins with 2 ^ 0
eg:
binary of 2 is 10 and want to check for 1st bit, then should the kth position be 1st position(i.e. binary 1) or 0th(kth - 1) position(i.e. binary 0)?

Comment: define the word "better"? in which regard should one be viewed as better, to you?

Comment: Never rotate/shift your data, when it's clearly not needed, only rotate/shift the "bit pointer" `pos`.

Comment: @Eugene: I just want to know that which one is a good practice among shifting the number and shifting the bit mask?

Comment: `leftShiftingMask` may map to [`BT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Test) and is the most common way to see it (in C).  The "best way" depends on how the result is used.

Comment: The `pos` for both should begins with `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a way that is much easier to read (to me at least):

```
public static boolean bitSetOrNot(int num, int pos){
   BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{num});
   return bitSet.get(pos);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question and I don't want to use java API's. I just want to use my own logic to get better understanding of how bitwise operators works.

Comment: @AkshayaAmar I see, let's first see what you are really after and I'll edit the answer once I understand that

Comment: Which one is a good practice. Is it shifting the number or shifting the bit mask or both are equivalent?

Comment: @AkshayaAmar I would personally always go with `leftShiftingMask`. I have actually never seen a method which rotates the number.

Comment: I saw such rotation with number in some of the websites that's why I asked...

Comment: @AkshayaAmar understandable. what I meant is "never seen", is in either jdk code itself or the open source projects I contribue to. internet can be full of garbage, but you already know that I am sure.

Comment: I agree with your points, but somehow I am still not convinced why left shifting mask is better if that is the case...I want to know the reason...